# How can we use JSON result to pie chart in PowerBI. How do i convert JSON to Table

Tags: json, powerbi, pie-chart

I have below JSON result. I am trying to use this in Pie chart.
I am using Power BI desktop application.

```
[
  {
    "STATUS": "aborted",
    "CNT": 3
  },
  {
    "STATUS": "error",
    "CNT": 2
  },
  {
    "STATUS": "finish",
    "CNT": 3
  },
  {
    "STATUS": "NotStarted",
    "CNT": 11
  },
  {
    "STATUS": "sleeping",
    "CNT": 8
  }
]
```

Comment: Have you checked this solution: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/ ?

Comment: This is nice example.  I got the same solution from http://www.dutchdatadude.com/loading-multiple-json-files-using-power-query/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer can be achived by referring below links.
Thanks for the help !

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4621/using-power-bi-with-json-data-sources-and-files/

https://www.dutchdatadude.com/loading-multiple-json-files-using-power-query/

Answer (score 0):

Connect to the file as a JSON document, convert it to a table, and expand the columns.

Here's what the M code looks like after I used the Power Query GUI to create the steps:

```
let
    Source = Json.Document(File.Contents("C:\Users\aolson\Documents\SampleJSON.json")),
    #"Converted to Table" = Table.FromList(Source, Splitter.SplitByNothing(), null, null, ExtraValues.Error),
    #"Expanded Column1" = Table.ExpandRecordColumn(#"Converted to Table", "Column1", {"STATUS", "CNT"}, {"STATUS", "CNT"})
in
    #"Expanded Column1"
```

Comment: Yes indeed I have got the same concept by referring some blogs.I have posted same in my answer . Thank You. :)